# Django: get related objects of related objects and pass to template

Tags: django, orm, model, foreign-keys, django-queryset

In a Django app I have three models:

```
class A(models.Model):
     aId =  models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class B(models.Model):
    bId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    aId = models.ForeignKey(A)

class C(models.Model):
    cId =  models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    bId = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

There is a on-to-many relation between A and B, as there is between B and C. 
And there is a View class with `context_data`.  In the template I need to show and filter Bs, with their Cs. 
How can I pass All Bs related to an A and All Cs related to those Bs to my template (context)? 
I tried to get Bs and Cs separately in two arrays, but it seems not to be a good idea because I can not categorize Cs by Bs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you have an instance of `A` called `a`.

```
bs = a.b_set.all()
for b in bs:
    cs = b.c_set.all()
```

The iteration over the elements might be done in the template itself.

In order to avoid multiple queries you can [prefetch related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

Answer (score 1):

So this would be the code for your view. I am not sure from which object(s) are given in the args/kwargs.

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class YourView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'yourtemplate.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        a = kwargs.get('a')
        b = kwargs.get('b')
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        ctx['all b related to a'] = a.b_set.all()
        ctx['all c related to b'] = b.c_set.all()
        return ctx
```

If you have to combine querysets, say multiple querysets of cs for each b as @s_puria suggested, you can use the UNION operator https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#union